# Jquery problem in fetching the values through submit button

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-selectors

JQUERY code

```
  $('#cartSubmit').click(function() {


        var product_name  = encodeURIComponent($('#product_name').val());
        var barcode  = encodeURIComponent($('#barcode').val());
        var Quantity  = encodeURIComponent($('#Quantity').val());


            var postData    =   "product_name="+product_name+"&barcode="+barcode+"&Quantity"+Quantity;
            $.ajax
                ({
                   type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/example/index.php/cart/cartoutput',                      
                    data: postData,
                    success: function(html) {
                        //alert(html);
                        $('#cartDisplay').html(html);   

                        }
            });

        return false;
    });
```

VIEW code

```
     <tr><td  align="center" > <input type="submit"  value="SUBMIT" id="cartSubmit"/></td> </tr>
```

i am not able to display the output. What is the problem in the code

Comment: you can use form serialise method from jquery, from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post `$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());`

Comment: have you checked in firebug any errors?

Comment: do you get a response in firebug? does the alert inside `.success` fires? also make a error handler for your ajax call

Comment: its doesn't fires... tat submit button doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I've had trouble getting [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to work in the past as well. Try:

```
document.getElementById("#cartDisplay").innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the cart added by JS or ajax?

Is `cartSubmit` inside `cartDisplay` in the DOM?

Try changing:

```
$('#cartSubmit').click(function () {
```

To:

```
$('#cartSubmit').live ('click', function () {
```

Comment: document.getElementById(
[Break On This Error] Failed to load source for: http://localhost/example//js/example.js

Answer (score 0):

try the following and see if it works, also i have made an error handler

```
$('#cartSubmit').click(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour of the submit

   $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/example/index.php/cart/cartoutput',                      
      data: {product_name:product_name,barcode:barcode,Quantity:Quantity},
      dataType:'html', // i assumed you are returning html
      success: function(html) {
            alert("success");
           $('#cartDisplay').html(html);   
           },
      error:function(jxhr){ // make an error handler 
           alert(jxhr.responseText);
           }
        });       
});
```

Comment: i guess problem with the submit button...its not working if the id="cartSubmit" .. .if i remove it... its displays the output